# $\int_\gamma \frac{e^z}{(z^2+1)^2} dz$ where $\gamma$ is $C(0,2)$ traversed twice counter-clockwise.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Evaluate $\int_\gamma \frac{e^z}{(z^2+1)^2} dz$ where $\gamma$ is $C(0,2)$ traversed twice counter-clockwise. This $\gamma$ should be represented as a cycle I believe.

Hi all, I am wondering about how to evaluate this integral using the Cauchy Integral Formula.

I have tried to represent the integral as a linear combination of simpler integrals but I'm unsure how. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy Integral Formula for derivatives?

Comment: @Apocalypse Yes.

Comment: $\frac{e^z}{(z^2+1)^2}=\frac{e^z}{(z+i)^2(z-i)^2}$. Apply the formula.

Comment: What if z = i or z = -i? These are within the circle, no?

Comment: It's exactly due to the fact that these holes are inside the circle this problem is nontrivial, otherwise you will get answer $0$ immediately for any integration for a holomorphic function.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help. If I did not know the formula for derivatives, then what would be the best approach here?

Comment: That would be hard to handle since the Cauchy Integral Formula is only valid for functions with first order poles inside the contour, i.e., in the form $f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{z-w}$ where $g(z)$ is holomorphic. If there are poles of higher orders you have to use derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Given partial fraction expansion
$$\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2}=-\frac{1}{4(z-i)^2}-\frac{i}{4(z-i)}-\frac{1}{4(i+z)^2} + \frac{i}{4(i + z)}$$
[Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem) can be applied for each part individually, considering the [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number#Complex_analysis) of course.

$$\int\limits_{\gamma}\frac{e^z}{(z^2+1)^2} dz=-\int\limits_{\gamma}\frac{e^z}{4(z-i)^2}dz-\int\limits_{\gamma}\frac{ie^z}{4(z-i)}dz-\int\limits_{\gamma}\frac{e^z}{4(i+z)^2}dz + \int\limits_{\gamma}\frac{ie^z}{4(i + z)}dz$$

More details [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~az10000/complex-analysis.pdf) (section 6) and [here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/CV/CV3.pdf) (pages 9 and 12).